# Skipping Column in OFFSET Function depending on Month in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, offset

I am hoping someone can help me, I am looking for a formulae to help me provide figures.

The below table shows the sales items in Column A, I am looking to add columns C,E,G (basically every 2nd column depending on which month we are currently in). I have used the OFFSET function currently bur now I want to add columns inbetween (as below) to show the projected sales.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: About which programming problem are you asking here? It seems you are using a spreadsheet programm - please mention which one and edit the tags accordingly. Also, your question is unclear as to what the problem is. Explain why it is not possible to add those Columns C,E,G.

Comment: I am using excel. I am looking to add every second column together to provide a total in a separate column but the total will only show depending on the month. So if January is in Column A, February in C, March in E, April in G and the total is in I, I want to show the total as at March so it will only be columns A,C,E added (I have a constants on a different tab to provide the month for the formulae.

Comment: The question is still unclear. Are you looking for a way to sum over every second column in excel? Then try to google [sum every second column in excel](https://www.google.de/search?q=sum%20every%20second%20column%20in%20excel).

Comment: not sure what's unclear. I want to total every 2 Column (C,E,G) to show in J? But if we are in the month of February I only want column J to show the total of column C and E? The link you sent doesn't help but thanks.